# Scan lines are not gathered in generating a point cloud

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've have built a point cloud, nevertheless, it is not fully working in the sense that when I watch in rviz, it shows only scan lines. Of course I can I a kind of cloud if i set the decay value in rviz as high as possible, but, it is just a fake one if I do that. I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry), anyway, to build the point cloud.

What I can see is that since the code snippet(see below) for building the point cloud resides in a function, that always being called, including to provide a new scan. It seems that, it enter the function, the cloud object is deleted and replaced with a new one, instead of accumulated over time. Then, I start to put the cloud variable as a class member variable, even though, in the tutorial, it is declared as a local variable. The problem after making it a class member variable is that, in rviz the message is not received(a kind of complaint).

I've tried to comment the transformLaserScanToPointCloud call, and no scan lines at all appears. This could mean, it somehow enters the try block.

Anyone know how to improve this? or Am i using the wrong function transformLaserScanToPointCloud call to implement building a point cloud.

Thanks in advance.

The code snippet(resides in a callback function):

```
      sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;

      static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
      tf::Transform xform;
      xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LDD.pose.position.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.z));
      xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.z, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.w));
      tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time(pose3D_LDD.header.stamp), "base_link", "laser"));
      tfListener_.waitForTransform("base_link", "laser", previous_scan_.header.stamp, ros::Duration(2.0));

      try
      {
        projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link", previous_scan_, cloud, tfListener_);           
      }
      catch (tf::TransformException ex)
      {
        ROS_WARN("Problem: %s", ex.what());
      }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12785/scan-lines-are-not-gathered-in-generating-a-point-cloud/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To assemble over time, use [laser_assembler](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler). `laser_geometry` converts one scan into one cloud. If you want to assemble over time, you need to use that package. Or, you could always use the Point Cloud Library's default types and just add them together. I would strongly recommend the `laser_assembler` package though.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
Kindly contribute here(http://answers.ros.org/question/3757/laser_assembler-not-gathering-scan-lines), if you have time :-)

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
I think it's better for to start a new thread for this one. Good for the others and those who are contributing like you..

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-27**:
Proper frame_id, proper topic names? Try this tutorial: http://ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
I got your point :-) I've included some lines of XML code pertaining to the laser_assembler as above, but, it only gives one cloud topic in the option tab in rviz, after clicking it, it doesn't assemble. What could go wrong?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-27**:
You can just feed the output of the above into the laser_assembler and it will assemble it over time. You can specify how long to assemble for (it's a rolling buffer)

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
That means I can still use the above cloud to be added by the laser_assembler right instead of PCL one? I think it's easier to stick to what I have now and add them over time. But then I'll have a lot of cloud then.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-27**:
laser_assembler essentially takes your cloud and adds them together over time (laser_assembler also works on clouds).

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-27**:
laser_geometry essentially just changes the data type of the LaserScan (which consists of nothing but an array of ranges) to a PointCloud (which has an x, y, and z value for every point). laser_geometry is supposed to be generic. I have a laser scanner that produces four lines at a time and it works

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
But, would the laser_assembler be able to build out of my pose information like I did above? In the tutorial, it doesn't say much.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
Then, what is the point of naming it as a cloud if it just converts to only one cloud. I just couldn't see it.